# Scala: Store parameter names and types in a hash map

Tags: scala, types

I am relatively new to scala. I am trying to maintain a hash map containing list of attributes and their types in a hash map.
I tried something like this

```
val attribTemplate = new mutable.LinkedHashMap[String, Class]

attribTemplate("attr1") = classOf[Int]

attribTemplate("attr2") = classOf[String]
```

scala doesn't like it. I would like to do pattern matching on this type information later
How can I achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Class` is generic, and Scala isn't as cavalier as Java about allowing you to ignore facts like that. The following will work just fine:

```
val attribTemplate = new LinkedHashMap[String, Class[_]]
attribTemplate("attr1") = classOf[Int]
attribTemplate("attr2") = classOf[String]
```

And then:

```
scala> println(attribTemplate)
Map(attr1 -> int, attr2 -> class java.lang.String)
```

This is almost certainly a bad idea, though, and it's not idiomatic Scala. Especially if you're new to Scala, I'd suggest asking another question about your particular use case and avoiding reflection (and mutability, if you can) for as long as possible.

Comment: Also, this wouldn't work well for pattern matching due to type erasure. You would have to get into typetags and such...

Comment: …which in my book also falls into the "almost certainly a bad idea" category.

Comment: Thanks guys.. I want to read and write from a byte buffer based on this type information. This hash map holds the information about the attributes and their respective types. I want to use this to serialize and de-serialize into a byte buffer.

Comment: @Gladiat0r That's probably a borderline-ish case. There are definitely much better approaches in Scala—see [scodec](https://github.com/scodec/scodec), which is [amazing](https://twitter.com/djspiewak/status/566395617467846657)).